# SSIS Looping with Return Value from Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, execute-sql-task

I am trying to create a SSIS Package that loops based on the return value of a stored procedure run in the loop.  I keep getting a super NOT helpful error of:

> "Error: 0xC002F210 at Load Order, Execute SQL Task: Executing the query "EXEC ? = [Load_Focus_OrderNum] ?, 1" failed with the following error:
>   "Value does not fall within the expected range.".
>   Possible failure reasons:
>   Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
>   Task failed: Load Order"

Here is my setup:

[image]

The Load Order stored procedure loads a table with 500 orders at a time, then the last order number is returned (I have confirmed it returns correctly).

```
DECLARE @spOut int
EXEC @spOut = Load_Focus_OrderNum 1, 1
PRINT @spOut
```

Returns 638 as expected

I then want it to process the next 500 starting at the next order.

I'm calling my stored procedure with:

```
EXEC ? = sp_LoadOrders ?, 1
```

Procedure snippet:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LoadOrders] 
    (@PK_ID INT, @OrdType INT)
AS
     -- Loads OrderNumTbl table
    RETURN (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM OrderNumTbl ORDER BY ID DESC)
GO
```

My parameter mapping for it is:

[image]

And my expressions for the loop are:

[image]

What am I missing? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the parameter Mapping section, replace the parameter name value  with the parameter index >> replace `@OrderID` with `0` and `@T1_ID` with `1`

**References**

- [SSIS: Value does not fall within the expected range](http://sqlsolutions.blogspot.com/2013/04/ssis-value-does-not-fall-within.html)
- [SQL Server Central - SSIS: Value does not Fall Within the Expected Range](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlrnnr/2014/07/17/ssis-value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range/)
- [Parameters and Return Codes in the Execute SQL Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/parameters-and-return-codes-in-the-execute-sql-task?view=sql-server-2014#Return_codes)

Comment: I need the LoadOrder in the loop as it loads the table each pass.  The first pass I need to feed it an OrderID = 1, and then OrderID will equal the output of it from then on.  I think I just need to do #3 to fix my loop.

Comment: @Dizzy49 i will be waiting for your reply